# How to read and write in to pdf file stored in document library?

Tags: document-library

I need to read the pdf file from sharepoint document library and need to update and save it in another folder.

By google, I got to know that we can read text files from document library from the below link and is working fine for me.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0e18a8/read-a-file-in-a-document-library-in-sharepoint-2013-using-c/

is it possible to read pdf files as well and how to update and store them.

kindly help on this.

Comment: On google, search for how to read pdf file using C#. You will get reference. From SharePoint perspective i guess you will need only pass the filepath and person running this programs needs to have access on that path

Comment: Thanks, I have used c# code using itext sharp for my requirement and it is working fine...thank you :)

Comment: Hi Pradeep, you can add what you have done as answer and accept it. It may help other members in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read file from sharepoint document library and saved into local server path using following code.

```
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebURL"].ToString());
Web web;
SP.List docLibName;
SP.ListItemCollection docLibColl;
SP.ListItem item;
SP.File file;
SP.CamlQuery caml = new SP.CamlQuery();

item = docLibName.GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32("Id of the document"));
file = item.File;
context.Load(item);
context.Load(file);
context.ExecuteQuery();
var fileInfo = SP.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, item.File.ServerRelativeUrl);

Stream fs = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, file.ServerRelativeUrl).Stream;
byte[] binary = ReadFully(fs);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists("sourceFilePath"))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete("sourceFilePath");
            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create("sourceFilePath"))
                {
                     fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
         }
         else
         {
            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create("sourceFilePath"))
                {
                      fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                 }    
          }
```

once I saved file from sharepoint library to my local server, The code used for extraction and updating pdf is posted at [Replace Text using ItextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600750/itextsharp-replace-text-in-existing-pdf-without-loosing-formation/41136797#41136797)

please reach me for any queries